# FastAPI APIRouter prefix are showing twice. Why?

Tags: python, frameworks, fastapi

```
notecard_router = APIRouter(
prefix = "/notecard",
tags = ['notecard']
```

)

[image]

Hi, I am trying to include a router to my app, but for some reason, the prefix that I give in the API router comes twice in the API paths. I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Do you have a minimal, verifiable (complete) example that shows the issue? It's impossible to say without having a complete application setup that shows the issue.

Comment: Let me guess - your route definitions looks `notecard_router.get("/notecard/allnotecards"): ...` 
Am i right?

Comment: On the off chance you're using class-based views, there is an existing bug which causes this (https://github.com/dmontagu/fastapi-utils/issues/154). Fixed in this fork of the project (https://github.com/yuval9313/FastApi-RESTful).

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't structure the router the way you're expecting it to. The router's prefix applies to all paths registered with it, in your case:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter
app = APIRouter(tags=["notecard"], prefix="/notecard")

@app.get("/notecard/index")
async def root():
    ...
```

Ends up duplicating the `notecard` prefix. Your API Path actually becomes `/notecard/notecard/index` (That's `/prefix/path`. Prefix here is defined at the router level as `notecard`, and the path is `notecard/index`. Putting that together, we see that `notecard` repeated.)

Rather, omit the router prefix when you register a subpath, as you've defined the prefix at the router level already.

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter
app = APIRouter(tags=["notecard"], prefix="/notecard")

@app.get("/index")
async def root():
    ...
```

The above will fix your issue.

Cheers!

Comment: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#another-module-with-apirouter

Comment: No that didnt solve it and look at the link I dont think they use it like that.

Comment: Can you send us a snippet of your @app.get decorator line?

Comment: I ran into the same issue and unfortunately, this answer did not work for me.

Let me provide a complete example so that anyone could see the issue:

    import uvicorn
    from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter, Request
    from fastapi_utils.cbv import cbv

    router = APIRouter(prefix="/sample")

    @cbv(router)
    class Server:
        @router.get("/hello")
        async def connect(self, request: Request):
            return "world"

    app = FastAPI()
    app.include_router(router=router)
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=22222)

Comment: @user1476860 Refer to @Tanya Branagan's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71773379/fastapi-apirouter-prefix-are-showing-twice-why/71818946#comment133146350_71773379) regarding an issue with `fastapi_utils`. https://github.com/dmontagu/fastapi-utils/issues/154