# FastAPI duplicates APIRouter prefix

Tags: python, fastapi

Sorry for duplicating an existing [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71773379/fastapi-apirouter-prefix-are-showing-twice-why), but I ran into the issue and did not find a solution there

I would like to add a common prefix to a number of URLs which my server handles, without repeating it in code. I know that APIRouter class supports *prefix* parameter. However, when I tried specifying it, it appeared twice in the URL.

Here is a verifiable example:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter, Request
from fastapi_utils.cbv import cbv

router = APIRouter(prefix="/sample")

@cbv(router)
class Server:
    @router.get("/hello")
    async def connect(self, request: Request):
        return "world"

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(router=router)
uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=22222)
```

If you run this and go to *http://127.0.0.1:22222/docs*, you will see that this server handles the following URL: *http://127.0.0.1:22222/sample/sample/hello*

[image: API details]

Adding tags parameter as the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71773379/fastapi-apirouter-prefix-are-showing-twice-why) suggests does not change anything. The following code still handles /sample/sample/hello:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter, Request
from fastapi_utils.cbv import cbv

router = APIRouter(tags=["sample"], prefix="/sample")

@cbv(router)
class Server:
    @router.get("/hello")
    async def connect(self, request: Request):
        return "world"

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(router=router)
uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=22222)
```

Could you please explain why the prefix doubles and how to get rid of the duplicate?

Comment: Seems the cause is `@cbv(router)`. I also found [this issue](https://github.com/dmontagu/fastapi-utils/issues/154).

Comment: Thanks, @ivvija. Why don't you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in `fastapi_utils.cbv`: https://github.com/dmontagu/fastapi-utils/issues/154

For a maintained version see https://github.com/yuval9313/fastapi-restful/ ; https://pypi.org/project/fastapi-restful/

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter, Request
from fastapi_restful.cbv import cbv

router = APIRouter(prefix="/sample")

@cbv(router)
class Server:
    @router.get("/hello")
    async def connect(self, request: Request):
        return "world"

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(router=router)
uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=22222)
```

Serves the URL `http://127.0.0.1:22222/sample/hello`

Comment: Another workaround is to set the prefix when you include the router in the app ```app.include_router(router=router, prefix="/sample")``` instead of configuring the router